# How to reset a QGIS toolbar?

Tags: qgis

How can I move the toolbar if its holder is out of screen , like this?

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6xv9.png

Comment: you can reset the toolbars http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59373/how-to-restore-original-settings-menu-in-qgis-customization

Comment: Or you can switch off your toolbar (right click on gray space next to toolbars then find your toolbar) and switch it on again. It should be in right place now.

Comment: I move the toolbar in a final , in write in pythone console this qgis.utils.iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().move(5,5)

Comment: @Bujor Corneliu, sounds like you have an answer.

Answer (score 4):

*The solution, as mentioned in comments by the asker :*

The following python code run in the console can move the toolbar back within the screen :

```
qgis.utils.iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().move(5,5)
```

Another solution, mentioned by Mapperz can be found in [How to restore original Settings Menu in QGIS (customization)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59373)

Answer (score 0):

As an update, the original answer posted by @gisnside does not work with QGIS v3, and the following variation should be used instead:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar,'mSnappingToolBar').move(5,5)
```